# how to check if methods parameter is a stdClass Object

Tags: php

I am passing `$row` which has been assigned `$statement->fetchAll();` to it I am passing it to another class and I want to check if it's an stdClass Object within the method, for example if I wanted to check if it was an array I would do

```
public function hello(array $row)
```

how would I do it to check if it was a stdClass Object ?

Finally is this called type hinting ?

Comment: Since none of the answers actually mentioned it. Yes, this is called type hinting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well solution look like easy one.

`public function hello(stdClass $row)`

I checked with php version 5.3 it works. like passing a stdclass object works but all other types gave cacheable fatal error.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a little script that can help you to check if a variable is an object or if is a specific type of object, if not want to cast parameter function to desired type of object.

```
<?php
function text($a){

   if(is_object($a)){
       echo 'is object';
   }else{
       echo 'is not object';
   }

   //or if you want to be more accurate 
   if($a instanceof stdClass){
       echo 'is object type stdClass';
   }else{
       echo 'is not object of type stdClass';
   }

}

$b = new stdClass();
text($b);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question in the Title.

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually is right one.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're wanting to explicitly state what kind of object a function receives as a parameter:

If you're expecting a Person object:

```
public function talkTo(Person $person){

}
```

If you're expecting a stdClass object:

```
public function printOut(stdClass $row){

}
```

Need a Database object?

```
public function save(Database $db){

}
```